# Why does NVL2 returns NULL when it's not expected?

Tags: sql, oracle

Let preparation structure be

```
create table RESOURCE1(id number, valueA varchar2(255));
create table RESOURCE2(id number, valueB varchar2(255));
create table IDS(id number);

insert into IDS
  select 1 from DUAL
  union select 2 from DUAL
  union select 3 from DUAL
  union select 4 from DUAL;

insert into RESOURCE1
      select 1, 'ABC' from dual
union select 2, 'DEF' from dual;

insert into RESOURCE2
      select 3, 'GHI' from dual
union select 4, 'JKL' from dual;
```

The following query

```
select P.VALUEA, Q.VALUEB
     , NVL2(P.VALUEA, Q.VALUEB, P.VALUEA) FROM_NVL2 
     , case when P.VALUEA is null then Q.VALUEB else P.VALUEA end FROM_CASE
  from IDS
  left join RESOURCE1 P on P.ID = IDS.ID
  left join RESOURCE2 Q on Q.ID = IDS.ID
    order by ids.id;
```

produces

```
VALUEA  VALUEB  FROM_NVL2   FROM_CASE
 ABC    (null)    (null)       ABC
 DEF    (null)    (null)       DEF
(null)   GHI      (null)       GHI
(null)   JKL      (null)       JKL
```

Why does FROM_NVL2 column contain all nulls? I've been expecting that FROM_NVL2 will result in the same values as FROM_CASE did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic for `NVL2()` is [described](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions106.htm) as:

> NVL2 lets you determine the value returned by a query based on whether
>   a specified expression is null or not null. If expr1 is not null, then
>   NVL2 returns expr2. If expr1 is null, then NVL2 returns expr3.

The equivalent `case` would be:

```
(case when P.VALUEA is not null then Q.VALUEB else P.VALUEA end)
```

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. Your answer is so clear that now I think I'm dumb.

Answer (score 1):

From your `case` example it seems that you are trying to use `NVL2` as a means of null coalescing 3 values, or you have swapped the order `expr2` and `expr3`, which is not correct.

The equivalent of `case when P.VALUEA is null then Q.VALUEB else P.VALUEA end` would be:

```
NVL2(P.VALUEA, P.VALUEA, Q.VALUEB)
```

Which would be the same as basic NVL:

```
NVL(P.VALUEA, Q.VALUEB)
```